# How to show a preview of one angular component into another component?

Tags: angular, components

I am dynamically loading components into the design component and want to see the preview in to the preview. basically I want the same html in the preview component as design component has but with different styling. And want the preview to be updated upon the changes in the design component.

Comment: I am thinking if a an approach that might give that result. Create a canvas out of a copy of the DOM value of the component. Basically, you take a copy of the rendered component, add the changes and then make a canvas out of it.